# vshost32.exe has stopped working either debugging or myproject.exe

Tags: vb.net, callback, delegates, dllimport

I'm trying to integrate a scanner to my code, in the sample solution they provided, they use DllImport, Delegate functions, callback procedures, etc...

This is just my first encounter with dllImport, delegates, callback procedures, everytime I debug the solution they gave me, starting from initializing, then button click and then suddenly I always get an error "vshost32.exe has stopped working".

Here's my the code:

**Imported Functions from DLL:**

```
Private Declare Function rdInit Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal tmo As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function rdStart Lib "sb6lib" () As Integer
Private Declare Function rdsConfig Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal Wnd As Integer, ByVal confile As String) As Integer
Private Declare Function rdConfigAPI Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal tmo As Integer, ByVal tmo As Integer) As Integer
```

**Use of delegates to implement callback procedures.**

```
Public Delegate Sub FeederEmptyDelegate(ByVal x As Integer)
    Private Declare Function rdOnFeederEmpty Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal lpfeederempty As FeederEmptyDelegate) As Integer

    Public Delegate Sub AllDoneDelegate(ByVal x As Integer)
    Private Declare Function rdOnAllDone Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal lpx As AllDoneDelegate) As Integer
Delegate Function CodeLineVBDelegate(ByVal lpx As IntPtr) As Integer
    Private Declare Function rdOnCodeLineVB Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal lpx As CodeLineVBDelegate) As Integer
Public Delegate Sub ErrorDelegate(ByVal x As Integer)
    Private Declare Function rdOnError Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal lpx As ErrorDelegate) As Integer

    Public Delegate Function DocumentDoneDelegate(ByVal lpx As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function rdOnDocumentDone Lib "sb6lib" (ByVal lpx As DocumentDoneDelegate) As Integer
```

**On Command1_Click Event** -Stands for Initialize Button

```
Public Sub Command1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
        Dim rtnval As Object

        ' find the RDS and initialize the API
        rtnval = rdInit(-1)
        List1.Items.Add(("rdInit returns " & rtnval))

        If rtnval > -1 Then
            rtnval = rdConfigAPI(4101, 0)
            rtnval = rdsConfig(Frame1.Handle.ToInt32, ".\\DOCDES0.DES")
            List1.Items.Add(("rdsConfig returns " & rtnval))

            'Callbacks
            rtnval = rdOnFeederEmpty(AddressOf feederempty)
            rtnval = rdOnAllDone(AddressOf alldone)
            rtnval = rdOnCodeLineVB(AddressOf codeline)
            rtnval = rdOnError(AddressOf onerror)
            rtnval = rdOnDocumentDone(AddressOf docdone)

            Command2.Enabled = True
            Command1.Enabled = False
            Command3.Enabled = True
            ViewButton.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

**On Command2_Click Event** -Stands for Start Scanning Button

```
Private Sub Command2_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command2.Click
        Dim rtnval As Object
        rtnval = rdStart()
        List1.Items.Add(("rdStart returns " & rtnval))
    End Sub
```

**After the scanning (End Sub) it goes to the Callback function "codeline": (Debug Mode)**

```
Private Function codeline(ByVal x As IntPtr) As Integer
        ' called when a codeline is available
        Dim cl As String

        cl = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(x) 'conversion necessary as passed argument is a BSTR type string in sb6lib

        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New WriteTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf codeline), New Object() {x})
        Else
            yval.Text = "CL: " & cl
        End If

        codeline = 1
    End Function
```

and then the application stopped working ("vshost32.exe has stopped working").

Can sombebody tell me what causes the crashing of the application? Thanks!

Comment: You have multiple problems, the crash is no doubt because the string is not actually a BSTR.  Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() is the next best guess.  The vendor also has a COM component available, you *really* want to use that one instead.  Give them a call if you need help.

Comment: How am I going to convert the BSTR to a string? If it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I think im having a problem with the callback procedures, because, when I tried to comment all the callback procedures, it works fine. However, when I tried to put each callback procedures (one at a time) it started to crash again. Can you please tell me where did I go wrong?